# Scala matching findAllin does not work in if clause

Tags: string, scala, matching

I would like to find the index of a digit from a string and take the character until the digit. Here is how i did it

```
val r = "[0-9]".r
val strName="dkgngw3#ujhg"

  if  (strName.exists(_.isDigit)) {
    val mi = r.findAllIn(strName)
    val strNameTrim=strName.substring(0, mi.start)
  }
```

It works if I run just these two lines.

```
val mi = r.findAllIn(strName)
val strNameTrim=strName.substring(0, mi.start)
```

It returns error if run the whole thing in if clause. How can I do this properly?

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No match available
  at java.util.regex.Matcher.start(Matcher.java:343)
  at scala.util.matching.Regex$MatchIterator.start(Regex.scala:761)
```

Comment: Do you need the index of the *first* digit? Or do you just want to get the part of a string from the start till the first digit?

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to achieve. It makes no sense to check if a string contains a digit if you plan to use regex. It seems you will need a *replacing* logic here, not *matching*, but you need to clear out your requirements first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is not very clear, but I think you just want

```
strName.takeWhile(!_.isDigit)
```

This will return all the characters in the name before the first digit. If there is no digit the result will be the same as the original string.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to find the index of first digit you can use something like this:

```scala
strName.zipWithIndex.collectFirst { case (ch, i) if ch.isDigit => i }
```

Comment: thanks. strTame.zipWithIndex.filter(_._1.isDigit)(0)._2 This works better as i would like to have an int instead of an option

Comment: This can be shortened to `strName.indexWhere(_.isDigit)`.